# Is there a video game museum anywhere in Europe?

Tags: europe, museums, geek-travel

I'm looking for a museum that collects video games. Preferably, the museum should be located in Europe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Computerspielemuseum](http://www.computerspielemuseum.de/index.php?lg=en) in Berlin claims to have been "the world's first permanent exhibition devoted to digital interactive entertainment culture."

Comment: I was there last April and is a bit disappointing

Comment: Could you tell me a little bit more why it was disappointing for you?

Comment: I visited in 2019 and it was pretty good. Hard to find a comparable place out there IMO.

Answer (score 7):

Jan Orna has put together [a comprehensive list of European arcade museums](http://www.arcademuseum.eu/arcade.html) (all with over 20 playable machines):

- [Freddy's Pinball Paradise](http://www.freddys-pinball-paradise.de/), Echzell, Germany
- [Deutsche Flippermuseum Extraball](http://www.flippermuseum.eu/german-pinball-machine-museum-english-summary.html), Neuwied, Germany
- [Arcade Hry](http://www.arcadehry.cz/homepage), Cerveny Ujezd, Czech Republic
- [Pbal Gallery](http://www.pinballmuseum.hu/en/), Budapest, Hungary
- [For Amusement Only](http://www.for-amusement-only.de/), Seligenstadt, Germany
- [Muzeum Arcade](http://www.muzeumarcade.cz/), Moravska Trebova, Czech Republic
- [Baboon City](http://www.babooncity.dk/), Herning, Denmark
- [RetroGames](http://www.retrogames.info/about), Karlsruhe, Germany
- [Spilmuseet](http://www.playright.dk/museum/), Ikast, Denamrk
- [Big Ben Matic](http://www.bigbenmatic.it/), Lignano Sabbiadoro, Italy
- [Museum of Soviet Arcade Machines](http://www.15kop.ru/en/), Moscow, Russia
- [Arcade Street](http://www.arcadestreet.fr/), Paris, France
- [Museum of Soviet Arcade Machines](http://www.15kop.ru/en/), Saint Petersburg, Russia
- Sportland, Blankenberge, Belgium
- [Oldenburger Computermuseum](http://www.computermuseum-oldenburg.de/), Oldenburg, Germany
- [Hearth of Gaming](https://www.facebook.com/TheHeartOfGaming), London, U.K.
- [Geek Room](http://www.geek-room.com/), Asnieres sur Seine, France
- [Timewarp Arcade](http://www.timewarparcade.co.uk/), Bridgewater, U.K.
- [Lunapark Reflex](http://www.reflex.be/en/), Oostende, Belgium

Be sure to check out [the full site](http://www.arcademuseum.eu/index.html), as it has stats on each of the arcades, pictures, and more details.

*Depending on your definition, arcade museums may or may not fall under the category “video game museum”. I'm leaving this as community wiki so there can be 1 canonical arcade museum answer*

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to Italy, the Video Game Museum [ViGaMus](https://www.facebook.com/pages/ViGaMus-VideoGame-Museum-of-Rome-Italy/346698965279) in Rome will be the place to visit.

Answer (score 1):

[Arcade Planet](http://www.arcadeplanet.es/) in Seville, southern Spain, is open every weekend afternoon, and has more than 100 arcade games.

> The industry of video games designed for arcades, ceased to be present in Europe at the end of the year 2000. The new generation of domestic video games, abusive taxes, and the crisis caused that the recreational machines stopped being manufactured, and the most serious ... that these systems were destroyed so as not to pay the monthly fees that their owners had to pay just for having them.
>
> In Arcade Planet, we have managed to rescue and restore the best recreational games in history, while preserving the best games of all systems.
>
> Arcade Planet offers its incredible collection of Arcades for events, exhibitions, organizanazación of tournaments, and sessions of free game "free play".
>
> With this initiative, those who played in the 80's and 90's will remember the best moments of leisure in their lives ... and the new generations will discover the special interpretation of the game mode created for recreational salons ... where the only purpose is immediate fun.

Answer (score 1):

The [Centre for Computing History](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/) in Cambridge, UK has an extensive selection of old computers and gaming consoles, many powered on and set up ready to be played.